# Convert BMP image to PNG or JPG in Java without loading the entire image in memory

Tags: java, android, bitmap, jpeg, image-conversion

I am trying to use a BitmapRegionDecoder to load parts of a large Bitmap image in Android but am stuck because the BMP file format is not supported(only JPG and PNG).
Is is possible to "transcode" a bitmap image into JPG or PNG (compression doesn't really matter) without loading the entire image into memory?

Something like

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pngFile);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = bmpInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    // Process bytes to PNG format
    fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: Why not convert before you put the file on the device (on your machine or on the server)?

Comment: That is not an option the file is picked at runtime by the user

Comment: That doesn't prevent you from pre-encoding it.  You just encode all of his choices.  Using actual bitmaps, especially for large images, is a really weird choice these days-  the file size would be huge.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense I cannot preencode a file a user picks from his phone at runtime

Comment: How did he get the file on his device?  Encode it then.  It should never be on disk as an actual bitmap.  Nothing does bitmap these days.

Comment: How to encode it without loading it into memory is precisely the question being asked. Not whether bitmap is a format that should be used

Comment: Yeah, you're just not getting it.  At some point, someone created this file.  It should be turned into another format then.  It should never, at any time, be a bitmap while on their device.  Then you don't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it using this [PNGJ library](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj) , written in pure Java so usable in android, and which allows to write PNG files line by line without loading the whole image into memory.